# HIghlight a row based on Date age AND value of a cell

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I am currently trying to highlight a row if the DATE column is under  50 days and if the user column does not include the text "ADMIN"

So i am using the custom formula in Conditional formatting.
I've used =$E$3:$E>TODAY()-50 in order to highlight the row if the date column is under 50 days. However, I want to take it a step further and have it highlight the row if it also doesn't include the text "ADMIN" in the user column. So i tried
=($E$3:$E>TODAY()-50) & F:F >< "ADMIN") but obviously that didn't work as it isn't correct. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0):

A formula that does not do what you want it to is not a good guide for what it is you do want but please try selecting say A:Z and for a conditional formatting rule apply *Custom formula is* of:

```
 =and($E1>TODAY()-50, $F1 <> "ADMIN")
```